# Can you lower a bonfire intensity after burning a bonfire ascetic?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Is there any way to lower the bonfire intensity after burning an ascetic?

There was some information on the internet that burning an effigy would lower the intensity in addition to the impact on invasion/co-op. I'm getting the impression this is misinformation, though.

So, is there anything that can reduce the impact of an ascetic, or are you always headed up toward the intensity 8 cap?

Comment: 'What is done, cannot be undone'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is no, there is absolutely no way to lower the intensity. The burning of an effigy only impacts the online interaction as you mentioned, anything else you might've read is complete misinformation.

> `or are you always headed up toward the intensity 8 cap?`

Yes, you're always headed to the cap, whether you burnt an ascetic or continue the process of New Games.